# Attributes in elements closing tag?

Tags: html, web-standards

Is it considered valid to do the following:

```
<li>stuff</li class="randomlengthclassname">
<li>stuff</li class="shortclassname">
<li>stuff</li class="reallyreallylongarseclassname">
```

or do the attribute **have** to be in the opening tag?

Comment: No, it's not valid. Yes, they have to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have attributes on closing tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138006/can-i-have-attributes-on-closing-tags)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it isn't. You must use attributes in the opening tag.

Running `<a>test</a href="tst.html">` in [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/) results in this error:

> name start character invalid: only S separators and TAGC allowed here

Where S separators and TAGC are:

```
    S is "whitespace" separator

    [5] s =

        SPACE | (32) space
        RE | (13) CR
        RS | (10) LF
        SEPCHAR (9) HT

            -- http://xml.coverpages.org/sgmlsyn/sgmlsyn.htm#C6.2.1

    TAGC    ">"

            -- http://www.w3.org/TR/sgml.l
```

Answer (score 5):

This is **not** valid, and all attributes must be defined in the opening tag, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute has to be in the opening tag. The code which you have presented probably wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Attributes should appear in the element's *start* tag. Quoting the [W3C: On SGML and HTML Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2):

> ... Attribute/value pairs appear before the final ">" of an element's start tag.  Any number of (legal) attribute value pairs, separated by spaces, may appear in an element's start tag. They may appear in any order.

Answer (score 0):

[Closing tags may not contain attributes.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2)
But in [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2) you may omit the closing `LI`:

```
<!ELEMENT LI - O (%flow;)*             -- list item -->
<!ATTLIST LI
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  >

Start tag: required, End tag: optional
```

In XHTML, you may not.