# Can I have attributes on closing tags?

Tags: html

There are many people that mark closing tags like this to help identify the closing tag that goes with an HTML tag:

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.php">
      <img id="logoimg" src="images/as_logo.png" alt="Logo" border="0" />
    </a>
  </div> <!-- logo -->
</div> <!-- header -->
```

I was wondering if it is syntactically ok to do this:

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.php">
      <img id="logoimg" src="images/as_logo.png" alt="Logo" border="0" />
    </a>
  </div id="logo">
</div id="header">
```

> UPDATE: Here is the text from the spec on HTML5.3:

**8.1.2.2. End tags**
End tags must have the following format:

1. The first character of an end tag must be a U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN
   character (<).
2. The second character of an end tag must be a U+002F
   SOLIDUS character (/).
3. The next few characters of an end tag must be
   the element’s tag name.
4. After the tag name, there may be one or more
   space characters.
5. Finally, end tags must be closed by a U+003E
   GREATER-THAN SIGN character (>).

**8.1.2.3. Attributes**
Attributes for an element are expressed inside the element’s start tag.

Note that attributes are only allowed on START TAGS.

using @jbyrds idea; **using the HR tag allows you to see if you forgot the z attribute**:

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.php" id=link">
      <img id="logoimg" src="images/as_logo.png" alt="Logo" border="0" />
    </a><hr z="link">
  </div><hr z="logo">
</div><hr z="header">
```

Although this adds more text, 32 extra characters vs. the original or the tags having a hidden class, you can use CSS to hide them.

```
[z] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: validator.w3.org says: `</div id="logo"> -- name start character invalid: only S separators and TAGC allowed here`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? HTML is not designed to do that and I'm sure whatever it is that you're trying to achieve can be done without this method.

Comment: It is strictly for readability and documentation of code.

Comment: Guess I'll continue with the first example.

Comment: Love the idea for comments :)

Comment: @drudge thanks for actually checking - wish this didn't violate spec, so much nicer than giant html comments

Comment: Wordpress strips out the comments and I need to see where the tags end in the html.  I really wish I could do this.  I know duplicating the id attribute is a bad idea since they should be unique but how about a data attribute? </div data-id="logo">

But there is hope. If you are brave enough, you should be able to use semantic tagging e.g. <maincontent></maincontent>

Comment: If you need to see where the tags end and you can't use comments because they get stripped out, you can always add a tag with an id or some other attribute right before the closing tag (and add a class to hide), like: `<br data-end-tag-id="logo" class="hidden"></div>`

Comment: @jbyrd... Never thought about that one. That is a good suggestion. Using a simple tag like `<i>` would probably work better. Adding the same attribute on an end tag results in an **End tag had attributes** error.

Comment: I was hoping I could define my `title` attributes in the closing tag so I can push that text off to the right without obscuring the body of the tag that otherwise gets shoved way off to the right. I guess I could use variables to reference in titles to keep them short in the source.

Comment: Interesting.  I came here when I had the same idea, so my opinion is also that it would be nice if HTML allowed the id attribute in closing tags.  Another idea is that it might allow a "for" attribute (an idea HTML already had), or an "of" attribute (a new made-up attrib), or a "di" attribute (using a reflection of "id").  
I can imagine the HTML curators not wanting to spoil the purity of the language with this, while users of the language want a clean way to give matching information for readability.  
My last idea is that perhaps the dev editor can help out.

Comment: Shame it's not possible. Sometimes there's I wanna see the elements content without having to scroll 3 miles right.

Comment: Let's say I have a <tr> tag. I output it, then do some logic and then (based on the logic) would like to set either a class or and attribute so the <tr> can be selected by a css rule. Is this a stupid use case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no for most tags. However, you could argue that tags like "img" that can be self-closing, are able to have attributes in them. But these self-closing tags are taking the place of an opening tag and a closing tag, so it's not the same as having an attribute in a closing tag. To be honest, there is really no need for this, it would just create more for the browser to have to read and make the page size bigger.

Comment: The OP specifically stated that it was for helping to identify matching tags, ie it's for readability.  This isn't even an answer, it's an opinion.  @drudge covers it better in their comment citing the w3c validator's error output.

Answer (score 11):

Short answer, **No**.

*Use the comments instead.*

Comment: Point me to W3C doc that says so?

Comment: Well it's not part of the spec, so why would there be documentation on it? :)

Comment: For XHTML, http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-etag. For HTML5, http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#end-tags. HTML4 is defined in terms of SGML, for which the official ISO specification document is sadly not freely available.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, but it doesn't work and doesn't validate.

If you try other attributes in closing tags, then the browser skips the attribute. I tried it in several ways, tested it with ids and classes, and the css and the javascript didn't recognized them in the ending tag. 
Your best bet is the commenting.

EDITED

Or you could make your own html tags.

You must use hyphenation, and you should avoid

```
document.createElement('foo-bar');
```

Comment: I believe this answer is just as valid as drudge's comment on the original question, however the portion about making custom tags is confusing. How do custom tags solve the commenting problem?

Comment: You can define custom tags and then the opening and closing tag will bear the name you want, for example:
<x-logo>
....
</x-logo>

Answer (score 5):

no, not possible. some browser will ignore it, but maybe some other browsers will complain and won't display HTML correctly.

Comment: Which browsers will not display the HTML correctly?

Comment: @PeterV maybe some? I'm kind of hoping they'll all work. If I find out anything to the contrary and I remember this, I'll update here.

Answer (score 2):

The original question describes a specific scenario of four parts:

1. improving html code readability, and specifically: matching opening and closing `<div> … <\div>` tags;
2. while reading (debugging) the rendered html page source grabbed from the browser;
3. when the rendered source has been dynamically generated (server-side generated/processed) and also stripped of all comments before sending the webpage to the requesting client;
4. and in this case the question is specific to WordPress (the well known php CMS platform for creating websites, blogs, etc.).

The specific complexity here is that there is no one source file to look at on the server as the webpage was dynamically generated by code with input from many files, databases, APIs, etc.

AND

That as previously noted, a common technique of placing a comment at the end of each closing `<\div>` is not helpful here because Wordpress, has stripped all comments prior to serving the page, presumably to make the page size smaller.

**A Javascript Solution:**

Forget about trying to hack the html in an effort to circumvent WordPress and the browser and the standards. Instead simply re-insert the comments back into the rendered source like this.

When matching opening `<div id="myDivID">` and 
closing `</div>` tags this javascript may help. 
This function will comment every closing `div` tag 
and label it with the div’s ID attribute, producing 
a result like this:

```html
<div id="myDivID">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
        ... 
        anim id est laborum.
    </p>
</div><!-- end #myDivID -->
```

This will work even when the rendered page is 
stripped of comments (by WordPress as in the 
original question). Just trigger or inject the 
function at any point you like, then view or save 
the source. As others noted previously, using 
comments doesn't violate the spec as some other 
suggestions may.

This short function should be easy to understand and
to modify for similar purposes. (Note the `insertBefore`
workaround, as there is no JS `insertAfter` method.)

```js
var d = window.document;
insertCommentAtDivCloseTag(d);  

function insertCommentAtDivCloseTag(document) { 
    var d = document;
    var divList = d.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var div = {};
    for (div of divList) {
        var parent = div.parentNode;
        var newNode = new Comment(' end #' + div.id + ' ');
        parent.insertBefore(newNode, div.nextSibling);
    }
}
```

This is the quick and easy one-off solution. If that’s all you need skip the rest...

If WordPress/web development is something you do everyday you may wish to consider exploring some of the following:

Hack WordPress

Again forget about hacking the HtML standard and hack wordpress instead. In fact WordPress is designed to be hacked. Virtually every function WordPress uses in creating a webpage has a hook that you can use to override or alter what it does.

[Codex, The Rosetta Stone of WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/)

Find the one stripping out your comments and add a function to turn it off and on.

If it’s been thought of before, there’s already a plugin for it.

[WordPress Plugins Home Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/)

WordPress plugins come and go, some are maintained others not, some are very good, and some are poorly designed, some are just bad. So *caveat emptor*. With that proviso, I was able find such a plug-in in ten seconds, with one search, on the first try.

Beyond WordPress

For so many reasons, it is beneficial to serve the smallest possible version of your webpage and WordPress may not be the only actor dynamically altering your code or caching older versions.

Your WordPress Installation and Blog Post (database)

↓

WordPress Theme

↓

WordPress Plugins

↓

The HTTP Server, such as Apache and it’s Modules

↓

A Proxy Server such as Nginx

↓

A Hosting Provider

↓

A CDN, Content Delivery Network

↓

(More Network)

↓

Finally My Browser the Client

↑

Also any Caches Maintained by Any of the Above

Finally, if this sort of thing is or is becoming your job, you’ll eventually want to explore specialized IDEs and separate production and development servers.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting that the simple answer is No, my entire HTML life, I've identified closing  tags by following with a comment. But long ago, it became impossible to nest comments. So when debugging, it is a royal pain to comment out a `<DIV>...</DIV>`, because of that identifying comment. Closing the DIV comment this way makes the comment closure hard to spot.

```
<!--
</DIV>--><!-- END DIV NAMEOFDIV -->
```

It is better placed on its own line, but this both hard to read and involves too much temporary manipulation...

```
<!--
</DIV>
-->
<!-- END DIV NAMEOFDIV -->
```

I'm no expert in such issues, but from this HTML end-user's view it seems absolutely absurd that a closing DIV can't be easily identified.

I will experiment with other kludges, such as adding a useless `<i CLOSES NAMEOFDIV></i>` tag. Or maybe a fake, meaningless tag? (e.g., `<ENDDIV NAMEOFDIV>`) (The nondisplayed HR z= trick is neat, but yet another visual confusion.)

We really shouldn't have to.  What were the powers that be thinking?