# How can I make comments in a /DIV (to indicate what it closes)

Tags: html

I'd like to be able to leave a comment inside of a closing `</div>` indicating what it goes with.

Could I just do `</div   comment="blah blah">`  ?

Is there a better way?

Comment: What about `<!-- -->` behind it?

Comment: More on this see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138006/can-i-have-attributes-on-closing-tags

Comment: @Progman  It's too easy for the comment to get separated from the </div> it describes. And a stray comment is more confusing than none at all.

Answer (score 5):

Attributes are not comments. End tags may not have attributes. Comments may not appear inside any tag.

You can put a comment *after* a tag.

```
</div><!-- blah blah -->
```