# Show item before loading AJAX reply

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to show an item if the user clicks on my button which is connect with my AJAX response. The div should by show after clicking button and hidden after the whole page is loading.

My AJAX:

```
document.getElementById('mainContent').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('productDetail').style.display = 'block';
//ajax
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML =
    this.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "product/" + id + "/", true);
xhttp.send();
```

I try this:
(I added a show div if the code is loaded and I wanted to hide it after loading)

```
document.getElementById('divForShow').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('mainContent').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('productDetail').style.display = 'block';
//ajax
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML =
    this.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "product/" + id + "/", true);
xhttp.send();
document.getElementById('divForShow').style.display = 'none';
```

I also tried
(The concealment code I wanted to associate with the onload event in the last div from the ajax response)

```
document.getElementById('divForShow').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('mainContent').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('productDetail').style.display = 'block';
//ajax
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML =
    this.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "product/" + id + "/", true);
xhttp.send();
```

*and added onload function on the end of my div in html AJAX response

```
</div id="myLastDivFromAjaxRespone" onload="hiddenDiv()">

document.getElementById('divForShow').style.display="none"; //hiddenDiv function
```

How to show the div after clicking the button and hide if the entire AJAX response has been loaded.

Comment: Closing tags doesn't accept attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138006/can-i-have-attributes-on-closing-tags

Answer (score 1):

You can simply split the code in 2 functions.
Then, on button click, calls the before_ajax(), then 
Example:

```
function before_ajax(){
document.getElementById(".element").innerHTML = "<b>Loading...</b>";
}

function do_ajax(){
document.getElementById('mainContent').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('productDetail').style.display = 'block';
//ajax
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML =
    this.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "product/" + id + "/", true);
xhttp.send();
}
function reload_page(){
window.location.reload();
}
```